# Molecular orbital explanation of why the protonation of the oxygen atom makes a carbonyl group more electrophilic

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, molecular-orbital-theory, carbonyl-compounds

I was working on nucleophilic addition reactions to the carbonyl group (namely, hemiacetal formation) when I came across the following explanation for the use of acid catalyst and how it increases reaction rate:

> In acid (dilute HCl, say), the mechanism is different in detail. The first step is now protonation of the carbonyl group’s lone pair: the positive charge makes it much more ***electrophilic*** so the addition reaction is faster.

The reaction at hand is the following:

[image: Hemiacetal formation mechanism]

Ignoring the presence of the positive formal charge on the oxygen, I am trying to understand on a molecular orbital theory level why this makes sense. I'm suspecting that this somehow lowers carbon's LUMO (${π}^{*}$ orbital), which would enhance the electrophilicity of carbon.

Would someone be able to give an explanation to the enhanced electrophilicity of the carbonyl group based on **molecular orbital theory**?

**References**

Clayden, J., Greeves, N., Warren, S. Organic chemistry, 2nd ed.; Oxford University Press: New York, 2012.

Comment: I think title should reflect you wanna talk about MOs.

Answer (score 4):

> Ignoring the presence of the positive formal charge on the oxygen

I think this is exactly what is responsible, even from the MO viewpoint. From the MO perspective, the electrophilicity of the carbonyl group can be viewed as how energetically-accessible is the $\ce {C=O \pi ^*}$ MO to the nucleophile's HOMO. The protonation of the oxygen atom effectively decreases the energies of all MOs of the carbonyl, including the $\ce {C=O \pi ^*}$ MO. Why? The proton is positively-charged. By attaching to the oxygen atom, there is a net decrease in the potential energy of the molecule due to there being more electron-nuclei attractive forces in the resultant entity. Hence, protonation makes the $\pi ^*$ LUMO more accessible to the attacking nucleophile, increasing electrophilicity.

Comment: Wouldn't that interaction be only between the oxygen and hydrogen atom? Or does that interaction affect the electrophilicity of the C atom?

Comment: That is not true. The positive charge is more delocalised than that. The protonation will cause all the electrons in the molecule to redistribute themselves.